# Ranger: How can I yank the selected files from commands.py?

Tags: ranger

I copied this snipped from the arch wiki. But instead of extracting the selected files, it extracts the yanked files. So I'd like to know **one** of this two things:

1. How can I make extract_here using the selected files instead of the yanked files?
2. How can I yank the selected files automatically from commands.py?

   ````py
   class extract_here(Command):
   def execute(self):
       """ Extract yanked files to current directory.
           HOW TO USE: press yy to yank, then call the method
                       with a shortcut or the command itself."""
       copied_files = tuple(self.fm.copy_buffer)

       if not copied_files:
           return

       def refresh(_):
           cwd = self.fm.get_directory(original_path)
           cwd.load_content()

       one_file = copied_files[0]
       cwd = self.fm.thisdir
       original_path = cwd.path
       au_flags = ['-X', cwd.path]
       au_flags += self.line.split()[1:]
       au_flags += ['-e']

       self.fm.copy_buffer.clear()
       self.fm.cut_buffer = False
       if len(copied_files) == 1:
           descr = "extracting: " + os.path.basename(one_file.path)
       else:
           descr = "extracting files from: " + os.path.basename(
               one_file.dirname)
       obj = CommandLoader(args=['aunpack'] + au_flags
                           + [f.path for f in copied_files], descr=descr,
                           read=True)

       obj.signal_bind('after', refresh)
       self.fm.loader.add(obj)
       ```
   ````

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
class extract_here(Command):
def execute(self):
    """ Extract selected files to current directory."""
    import os
    from ranger.core.loader import CommandLoader
    cwd = self.fm.thisdir
    copied_files = tuple(cwd.get_selection())

    def refresh(_):
        cwd = self.fm.get_directory(original_path)
        cwd.load_content()

    one_file = copied_files[0]
    cwd = self.fm.thisdir
    original_path = cwd.path
    au_flags = ['-X', cwd.path]
    au_flags += self.line.split()[1:]
    au_flags += ['-e']

    self.fm.copy_buffer.clear()
    self.fm.cut_buffer = False
    if len(copied_files) == 1:
        descr = "extracting: " + os.path.basename(one_file.path)
    else:
        descr = "extracting files from: " + os.path.basename(
            one_file.dirname)
    obj = CommandLoader(args=['aunpack'] + au_flags
                        + [f.path for f in copied_files], descr=descr,
                        read=True)

    obj.signal_bind('after', refresh)
    self.fm.loader.add(obj)
```

[Edited in the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ranger#Archive_extraction), hopefully no one will ever have this problem again.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'problem'. The previous version was able to extract into any directory while your version is not.

Comment: The name of the class is 'extract_here', not 'extract_into'.

Comment: Yes - you yank the files you want to extract, go to the desired directory and then 'extract them here'.